# Create Microsoft Access SQL queries on the fly

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to link to circa 270 (amount can change) .txt files and create a select query on all of them. I can import them all at once no problem, but as Access can only handle 32 tables per select query I need some way to create a variable (on the fly?) which will hold a SQL string which will then be used as a parameter in a create query def function. Does anyone have any ideas. I'm thinking I need to use a class, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Could you add a bit more verbiage to your question? Maybe add some sample data? There are plenty of Dynamic SQL building techniques available on the internet. 270 SELECT queries sounds odd.

Comment: You mentioned link, query, and import.  Is the purpose here to import data from text files into Access, or maybe just subsets of the columns from those text files?

Comment: Hi Paul. I can create the SQL queries at run time ok, but the number of queries can be changeable. Sorry for any ambiguity, but I need to add a table to a query (left join) until I get to 32 tables, then execute that query, then I need to start building a new SQL string for a select query for the next 32 tables. Any code I have now is useless, as I am having trouble thinking about how to approach the problem. I can create a SQL query in VBA for all 270 tables but it's 'too complex', so I guess I need to do several hierarchies of select query. Confused???

Comment: @ HansUp - Importing is easy, it's just doing the queries on the fly for the number of tables that I'm having trouble with. If only you could create a variable in a function and call that function multiple times :(

Comment: Can you import all the .txt files into the same database table, with a field to identify the source file?  The a single query can easily access them all at once, and select on or report back the source file as needed.

Comment: @empty - how are the ~270 txt files determined? via a DIR (on 1 or more folders?) or via Select FileName from a table of files?  Why not just read the files one at a time, for all 270 iterations, to build them into a db table. Which then can be queried...  For the load, just iterate thru each of the ~270.  What is gained by trying 32 at a time?

Comment: @donPablo, the ~270 .txt files have flow data, one entry per day but each file may not have a reading for each day; so what I've done so far is to create a union query to get all available dates, and then I'm doing a select query on all tables against the union query with each file name effectively being the field name in the select query. Will appending them will acheive what I need? Any help is helpful. Martin T (MT = empty)

Comment: @ Don George, please elaborate on how to import so many files into one table. Or are you asking me??? Sorry for any confusion. Martin

Answer (score 0):

My approach in a similar situation is to put all of the input files in a common folder, with nothing else in that folder.  Then I use the following vba script to process all the files.  For each file, I add the file name to a directory table (".import files") and the data to a second table (".import data").  The "source" field in the data is the link to the "Index" field of the files list so I know which data came from each source file.  It doesn't matter how many files are in the folder.  (If you prefer, you can change one of the two tables so these 2 fields have the same name if I had been thinking ahead more, I would have done so.)

My input files aren't particularly well formatted (and I cannot control the data source), but at least they are all in the *same* poor format.  Specifically, there are not field names in the first row of the data.  That's why I import them to a temporary file, and in the "insert into" command has fields in the source table like F1, ... F9.  You'll need to change the lines that build the SQL "Insert into" statement to match your file formats.

You will also need to create the directory and data files before you run the code - you can create the data file by importing one of the source files as a template, then editing it to add the "Source" field.  The 3 fields in the ". import files" table are Index (which is an auto-number field), file name and update date.

When you are done with this, you'll have two tables that you can join on "source" (from .import data) and "index" (from .import files).  Then you can continue with whatever processing you require.  You can select on "Source" to look at a specific input file, or group by "Source" to summarize the data by input, or ignore "Source" all together to get a summary of all of your data.

```
    Function Import_BTT()

    'On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'Get folder & file list
    Source_folder = Get_Folder()
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set flist = fso.GetFolder(Source_folder).Files

    'delete prior data
        Set DB = CurrentDb()
        DB.Execute ("delete * from [book to tax import files];")
        DB.Execute ("delete * from [book to tax import data];")

    'Process each file
    For Each file In flist
        If (Len(Dir(Source_folder & "\" & file.Name)) = 0) Then GoTo NextFile

        'add new data
        DB.Execute "insert into [Book to Tax import files] ([file name],[update date]) values (" & "'" & file.Name & "',#" & file.DateLastModified & "#);"
        Source = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
        DoCmd.TransferText , , "Book to Tax import Temp", Source_folder & "\" & file.Name

        SQL = "INSERT INTO [Book to Tax Import data] (source, Account, [Book Balance], [Book Adjustments], [Adjusted Book Balance], [Tax Reclass], [Balance After Tax Reclass], [Tax Adjustments], [Historical tax Adjustments], [Tax Balance] )"
        SQL = SQL & "select '" & Source & "',mid(F1,instr(f1,'(')+1,10),F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9 FROM [Book to Tax import temp] where ((trim(f1) like 'BK (*') or (trim(f1) like 'TAX (*'));"

        DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Book to Tax Import Temp"

    NextFile: Next file

    MsgBox ("data import completed")
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    End Function

Public Function Get_Folder()

'Create a FileDialog object as a Folder Picker dialog box.
Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker = 4
Const msoFileDialogFilePicker = 3
Const msoFileDialogViewDetails = 2

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
fd.ButtonName = "Select"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
fd.Title = "Select Folder"
fd.InitialFileName = "MyDocuments\"
fd.Filters.Clear

'Show the dialog box and get the file name
If fd.Show = -1 Then
    Get_Folder = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
    Get_Folder = "MyDocuments\"
    End If

Set fd = Nothing
End Function
```